# Find IMG tag and get it's "src" from within a RSS feed node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This may be a very basic question. So please excuse me for the noobness. I'm trying to get myself familiar with xml traversing. Suppose I've this node

```
[content]
 <img src="some url" />
 <a href="some link">Some link</a>
 Some text after the link.
[/content]
```

As you can see, the node contains a mixture of text and tags. So I was wondering if I could target the `img` tag within that node and get it's `src` attribute?

I'm using `simplexml` to read the xml file.

If I do just `$xml->content`, the browser is showing an image, a link and the text. So I was hoping there was some option to "find" the `<img>` tag within the `content` node.

#### UPDATE

Okay. I think I might have used the wrong technical terms. Are RSS feeds are XML one and the same? I'm getting the XML feed from this [URL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=2/genre=6014/xml)

Comment: You are looking for HTML inside CDATA (text) elements of the RSS Feed XML. For the HTML, you find the answer in a duplicate question. For the XML, there are *tons* of duplicate quesitons. Stackoverflow works best asking one question at a time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it figured it out myself. What I did was take the entire content of the `[content]` node and then use `preg_match` to find the `<img>` tag from it.

```
$content = $xml->content;
preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $content, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment content is not a XML node. It should be formed like this;

```
<content></content>
```

To get the image source just do;

```
$xml->content->img['src']
```

Simplexml makes nodes accessible via '->'. 
Node attributes are accessible via array notation '["attr name"]'

Hope this helps you

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed, just blank

Comment: Because the source given (feed/entry/content) is partially html entities encoded.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<?php

    $html = '
        <body>
            <img src="some url" />
            <a href="some link">Some link</a>
            Some text after the link.
        </body>
    ';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        if ($child->getName() === 'img')
        {
            $attributes = $child->attributes();
            $img_source = $attributes['src'];
            echo $img_source;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Apologies. My file does not seem to be an XML. I updated by question content.